# Easy C++ bloodshed dev c++

Tags: c++, double, formula

Why is this printing 1??? Its driving me INSANE. Should be printing 1.01005016708

I am using bloodshed dev c++ to compile

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double rate = .05;
    double time = (1/5);
    double p = exp(rate*time);
    cout<<p<<endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 double time = (1/5);
```

should be

```
 double time = (1.0/5);
```

Otherwise, `time` will get `0.0` because of integer division truncation. Therefore, `p = exp(0.0)` will be 1.

Answer (score 3):

1 / 5 is integer division -- the operands are both integers, thus you'll get 0.

Use 1.0 / 5, to ensure that at least one operand is **double** & and that your division will be performed as floating-point double.

Two integer operands, will give you integer division.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this isn't the answer to your question, but Thomas and tacop got that covered.

You should look for a new IDE to use, i myself switched to code::blocks and i think it's great, but here are some reasons why:

> 1. Dev-C++ has not been updated since 2005, and is not currently maintained. The software is very buggy.  At the time of my writing
>      there are 340 known bugs that will never be fixed.
> 2. It’s hard to get help, because the programming community have moved on to newer software.
> 3. Dev-C++ lacks features that are present in more modern solutions. Code completion, intellisense, and proper debugging facilities (among
>      others) are not provided.  These tools can greatly improve the
>      workflow and efficiency of an experienced programmer, and may aid the
>      learning of beginners.
> 4. Error messages and the steps required to solve them are poorly documented compared to more modern solutions, and because most
>      programmers have moved on from Dev-C++ it can be difficult (if not
>      impossible) to find anyone who is able to help you.  Some problems may
>      not be able to be solved at all. The compiler included with Dev-C++ is
>      very out-dated, and buggy.  An out-dated compiler can result in buggy
>      and inefficient code, and may be damaging to the learning process for
>      a beginner.
> 5. The provided “devpack” system is no longer supported by modern libraries.  Using external libraries in Dev-C++ can be a confusing and
>      difficult process for beginners who are expecting this simple system
>      to handle it for them. There are plenty of modern, freely available
>      alternatives that do not suffer from the same problems, and it is
>      simply ridiculous that any beginner should end up using such a
>      horrible and out-dated tool as Dev-C++.

Plus you can get rid of that wretched `system("PAUSE");`

Comment: Last I heard, Dev-C++ got better: http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/. I do like C::B, though, but I haven't tried that updated version.

Comment: I saw that too, but i never tested it out, not sure how much better it is. Still, i think C::B is pretty neat :).